# Light text in dark status bar is not working in Android 11

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-11

I'm changing status bar color and text between fragments/activities. For black status bar I need white text and viceversa. Due to api deprecation on Android 11 I am using this:

**Dark status bar with light text:**

```
Window window = getWindow();
    if (mDefaultStatusBarColor == null) {
        mDefaultStatusBarColor = window.getStatusBarColor();
    }
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));

    // Sets status text light
    View decorView = window.getDecorView();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        WindowInsetsController wic = decorView.getWindowInsetsController();
        wic.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
```

**Changing to light status bar with dark text:**

```
Window window = getWindow();
            // Giving the status bar its default color.
            if (mDefaultStatusBarColor != null) {
                window.setStatusBarColor(mDefaultStatusBarColor);
            }

            // Sets status text dark
            View decorView = window.getDecorView();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController wic = decorView.getWindowInsetsController();
                wic.setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            }
```

But the first case (dark status bar with light text) is not working properly because text is still dark.

Did I miss to add something?

Answer (score 0):

since [SetSystemUIVisibilty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)) was deprecated in API level 30,
use [WindowInsetsController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController) instead:

```
final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
int systemBarsAppearance = insetsController.getSystemBarsAppearance();
// Sets status text light
insetsController.setSystemBarsAppearance(systemBarsAppearance, ~WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
// Sets status bar dark
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0xff000000);
```

All the best!